# How to write correct syntax for myname

Tags: php

It should be

> $value = Suria

```
<?php 

    $value = print($D->myname);
     $year = 1980;

?>
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: can you show us you query ?

Comment: lacking of details about what is the problem is

Comment: I can echo this way `<?php echo $D->myname?>`  will display  `Suria`

Comment: we don't know your code... what is `$D` and how is it built ?

Comment: Sorry question updated.

Comment: I just change to print does not work!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the w3schools example:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name FROM YourTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why downvoted? The OP asked for an example.

Comment: Question is *waaay* to broad, and just grabbing the code from W3S isn't really a good way to answer a question either..

Comment: @Qirel Oh really??? Maybe the person who asked the question is a pure beginner and asked such a `waaay to broad` question because he or she does not know where to begin? Many people ask such questions when they begin to learn something. My answer is just a hint to play with. It wouldn't have been nice if I hadn't indicated the source my answer was based upon.

Comment: Sure, I'm all for helping out - but there's literally no code in the question to support the question - this platform isn't really about writing code for others, it's about troubleshooting and getting help for existing code that isn't working. If there's no basis, a tutorial is a better place to start than StackOverflow, really.

Comment: @Qirel Well, then the community members should politely indicate the place where to start like w3schools or anything else instead of ruthlessly downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you did a *request* to your *database* with `PDO`.
After executing the query, *fetch* it to use it as an `array`.

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("YOUR QUERY STRING");
$req->execute();

$myarray = $req->fetch()
// The result of the request is saved in this variable as an array
// use $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) if you want an associative array

echo $myarray['my_value'];
// my_value is your myname
```

Also, you are giving the function `print()` to your variable `$value`. You should give a value to your variable and print it after:

```
$value = $myarray['my_value'] // I continue with the code I wrote above
print($value); // will write your variable
```